# Add fixed/absolute content to bottom and create new page if needed

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm generating a PDF where I need a table to be printed at the very end of the document.

This code is working partially

```
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0mm;">
```

The problem is, if there's not enough space at the bottom it will be placed above whatever text is there. So, is there any way to create a new page and add that fixed content to the bottom?

I have tried with 'setAutoBottomMargin' => 'stretch' and 'setAutoBottomMargin' => 'pad' without luck.

Comment: You can certainly put in a page break. Not sure about the “if there’s not enough space” part.

Comment: I know that but that page break it's only needed if the fixed div is bigger than the remaining blank space.

Comment: Wondering if you could make a different footer for last page only and shove the table into a footer (just spitballing here, not testing....)

Comment: That's actually the first thing I did. The result is the same. The footer overlaps with the content. It doesn't create a new page just to add a different footer.